# OpenGL lighting and shading on a GL_QUAD_STRIP

Tags: opengl, geometry, light

New to OpenGL, trying to implement a sphere with shading and lighting.  I am aware that there is a sphere function I could call on, but trying to create my own.  However, while I can get lighting and shading on other objects in the scene (such as glcubes, etc.), I am unable to get any shading or lighting on the sphere.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Bellow is my function to draw the sphere:

```
void cg_SolidSphere( GLint slices, GLint stacks )
{
    float x, y, z ;
    for( float lat = 0 ; lat < PI ; lat = lat + PI/stacks )
    {
        glBegin( GL_QUAD_STRIP ) ;
        for( float lon = 0 ; lon < 2*PI ; lon = lon + 2*PI/slices )
        {
            x = cosf( lat ) * sinf( lon ) ;
            y = sinf( lat ) * sinf( lon ) ;
            z = cosf( lon ) ;
            glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
            x = cosf( lat + PI/stacks ) * sinf( lon ) ;
            y = sinf( lat + PI/stacks ) * sinf( lon ) ;
            z = cosf( lon ) ;
            glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
        }
        glEnd() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `glNormal3f` calls, too. In this case, the normal is the same as the vertex, so we can use the same points:

```
x = cosf( lat ) * sinf( lon ) ;
y = sinf( lat ) * sinf( lon ) ;
z = cosf( lon ) ;
glNormal3f( x, y, z ) ;
glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
x = cosf( lat + PI/stacks ) * sinf( lon ) ;
y = sinf( lat + PI/stacks ) * sinf( lon ) ;
z = cosf( lon ) ;
glNormal3f( x, y, z ) ;
glVertex3f( x, y, z ) ;
```

Comment: @ElfsЯUs: Probably with [`glMaterial`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMaterial.xml).

Comment: How would you add texture coordinates on the above algorithm?

Comment: @ladiesMan217: You could probably use `lat` and `lon` (scaled appropriately) as texture coordinates.

Comment: Yea, but in the above formula you are only drawing 2 vertices using `GL_QUAD_STRIP`. There has to be 4 vertices. Hence, when I render texture coordinates it doesn't cover the whole of it. But then again, when I add the other 2 vertices, it messes up the whole sphere.